# VS Code - Task to run batch in current cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have my VS Code setup to run a bat file to setup my env variables when I open a new cmd terminal. (Windows 10)

I can not figure out how to get a task to run a bat file inside that same cmd though. Each task runs in its own cmd instance and ignores the environment variables.

Any way to target the current terminal instance when running an external command?

Comment: why not just run that bat file to setup your env variables for every cmd terminal?